# Code execution on CUDA/CPU

Tags: function, cuda, gpu, cpu

Is there any way to find out in the `__host__ __device__` function code is executed on CUDA or on CPU?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpreted your question as:

> is there any way to know in a `__host__ __device__` function whether the code it's being executed on the device or on the host?

As of today there's no runtime *officially reliable* trick to detect it. Anyway you could use the `__CUDACC__` macro to "specialize" your code for device and/or host:

```
__host__ __device__ void yourfunction() {
  #ifdef __CUDACC__
     // Device code branch
  #else
     // Host code branch
  #endif
}
```

Reference: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#host